# Pronunciation of "China" in German

Tags: pronunciation, regional, standard-german

In German there is some confusion on how to pronounce the letters **'ch'** in *"China*". I heard all of following variants:

> **[ˈçiːnaː]** - as in *"i**ch**"*
>   **[ˈkçiːnaː]** - as in *"Bä**ckch**en"*
>   **[ˈkiːnaː]** - as in *"**K**ino"*
>   **[ʃiːnaː]** - as in *"**Sch**nee"*
>   **[tʃiːnaː]** - as in *"**Tsch**üss"*

These differences seem to be regionally accentuated but still they are variable. Which pronunciation is accepted? Are there variants that should better be avoided?

Comment: Accepted pronunciation: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/China

Comment: How do Tyroleans pronounce it? Analogous to *Kind* I could imagine /kxi:na:/ … Splattne? ;)

Comment: @Jan [kiːna], and if you say "t͡ʃiːna" they'll give you some Kaːzʃpat͡səl

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The 'correct' standard German pronunciation for China is /'ç.../) but in Southern Germany and in Austria they say 'Kina' (/'k.../).

In some regions (for example where I live) some people say 'Schina' (/'ʃ.../), but they also say 'isch' instead of 'ich' or 'Mädschen' instead of 'Mädchen'. That is, we pronounce the 'ch' in a different way, but that's not necessarily considered wrong, though it's not standard German.

The best way (imho) is to say /ç/ as in 'ich', then everyone will accept it.

Edit:
I found a [wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_%28Digraph%29) giving some pronunciation rules. Amongst other things it says:

> Außerdem kommen für ch auch die Aussprachen als sch [ʃ] und tsch [tʃ]
>   vor:
>
> - wie [ʃ] als umgangssprachliche oder varietätenspezifische
>     Variante von [ç] am Wortanfang (Chemie, China),
> - in nicht (vollständig) integrierten Fremdwortschreibungen vor allem
>     aus dem Französischen und Portugiesischen (als [ʃ]: Champignon,
>     Charlotte, Recherche), dem Englischen und Spanischen (als [tʃ]: Chip,
>     chatten, Macho).

This means it is acceptable to pronounce it as /ʃ/.

As summary:
You can say China, Schina and Kina, but in case of this country there seems to be no 'Tschina'-pronunciation, although it is possible for some other words starting with 'Ch'.

An additional information: The same is valid for 'Chemie', but NOT for 'Chemnitz' and 'Chiemsee'. Both are spoken with the K-sound.

---

I want to link an article from belleslettres.eu about [the right pronunciation of the word *Chemie*](http://www.belleslettres.eu/blog/chemie-aussprache.php). You should notice this quote:

> Welche Aussprache Ihnen auch immer eigen ist, Sie liegen damit richtig. Denn für die drei Varianten /ʃ/, /ç/ und /k/ finden sich jeweils so viele Sprecher, daß man von keiner Standardform durch Mehrheit sprechen darf.

Comment: Other words starting with "Ch" and spoken as "K": Cholera, Chlor (chlorine). Both words have roots in the Greek language, AFAIK.

Comment: @0x6d64 This is absolutely correct, there are much more words (Chaos, Charisma, Chor,...). But as far as I know, for these words the pronunciation is never questioned.

Comment: To my ears, the schina-variant [ʃiːnaː] does not sound like standard German. I am living in Vienna and have lived and worked for some years in Berlin.

Comment: @The_Fritz That's exactly what I am saying by "That is, we pronounce the 'ch' in a different way, but that's not necessarily wrong, though no standard German." It is **not** standard German, but it is the usual pronunciation of some people.

Comment: @Em1 Also ich hab eine Menge Scharisma :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Nein. Das gilt eben nicht für alle Wörter, sondern nur eine handvoll. Ohne es genauer zu wissen, glaube ich, dass es sprach-historisch bedingt ist, welche Wörter anders gesprochen werden können. Wenn du dazu genaueres weißt, lass es mich wissen.

Comment: @Em1: Ich weiß - aber Schor, Schaos und Scharisma fand ich beim Drüber nachdenken extrem lustig :-)

Comment: Both the "Ausspracheduden" and Siebs "Deutsche Hochsprache" only give the "Ch" option for China (IPA: [çi:na]). Siebs writes (in my translation): "Ch is pronounced ç in the initial sound of greek words, notably (namentlich) in front of a light vowel: Charon, Eucharistie, Chemie [...], in orientalischen Wörtern wie [...] China [...]. The initial sound ç is transformed in the processes of Germanization (Eindeutschung) in "k", notably before dark vowel and consonant: [...] Chemnitz, Chor ...". Of course, this only applies to the standard language, in real life, [çi:na] and [ki:na] are regional.

Comment: Please correct your first sentence. You wrote »The 'correct' standard German pronunciation for China is /'ç.../) but in Southern Germany and in Austria they say 'Kina' (/'k.../).« As it stands there, this sentence says, that the Austrian pronunciation would not be 'correct'. This is wrong. The Austrian pronunciation [ˈkiːna] is also correct. It even is the only correct pronunciation of *China* in Austrian standard German.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Wer *Schemie* sagt, muss auch *Schlor* sagen ;)

Comment: @Jan Ja, das ist so eine Sache mit dem `ch`... Ich sage "Chemie", aber "Klor" und "Kor".